# Why is the matrix rank at least $k$ when some $k$ rows are strictly diagonally dominant?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A = \left[ {{a_{ij}}} \right] \in {\mathbb{C}^{n \times n}}$ and ${\rm{ }}{{\rm{R}}_i} = \sum\limits_{j \ne i} {\left| {{a_{ij}}} \right|} $ and ${\rm{|}}{{\rm{a}}_{ii}}{\rm{ |  >  }}{{\rm{R}}_i}$ for $k$ different values of $i$.

Why does $\operatorname{rank} A\ge k$ hold?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please always include some English words in the question title, so that on right-click, the browser's context menu is not overridden by the MathJax menu.

Answer (score 2):

*Hint.* Suppose the first $k$ rows are strictly diagonally dominant. Apply [Gershgorin disc theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem) to the $k\times k$ leading principal submatrix of $A$.